# Linux - Disable Kernel USB Check at boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb, kernel

I have the following problem:

The boot process of a PC is delayed by about 30 to 60 seconds because the kernel reports a defective USB cable.
After the boot process all USB devices work as usual. Even with no USB devices connected at all, this error message occurs.

How can I fix this error. Is the (comparatively quite new) motherboard unsupported hardware?
Can a USB check during boot be prevented or skipped?
Here is the output of `inxi -Fxz`

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.11-060211-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: Cinnamon 5.6.8 Distro: Linux Mint 21.1 Vera
    base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: ASUS product: N/A v: N/A serial: N/A
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: TUF GAMING X670E-PLUS v: Rev 1.xx serial: <filter>
    UEFI: American Megatrends v: 1222 date: 02/24/2023
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 7700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3
```

And here is the error message (output of `journalctl -p3 -b` ), which is also shown to me during the boot process:

```
Apr 19 08:48:38 lmj kernel: usb usb2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr 19 08:48:42 lmj kernel: usb usb2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr 19 08:48:46 lmj kernel: usb usb2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Apr 19 08:48:50 lmj kernel: usb usb2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Note that these are not the only lines. The error message is issued every second.

Comment: It isn't reporting a "bad cable" (and in any case it says "maybe"...) but some other problem with the USB hub, internal or external that you confirmed, apparently, by booting without additional USB devices. It may have to do with the firmware settings.